# How to get the exact count of lines in a very large text file in R?

Tags: r

I have multiple files with over 1.000.000 lines each, but I need to know the exact number of lines for each document using R. How can I achieve that?

Comment: There are several different ways you could go. I'm not sure what's most efficient with files of that size, but an easy solution would be something like `length(readLines(filename))`

Comment: works so far, I thought this one would fail at large documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) wc** This should be quite fast. First determine the filenames.  We have assumed all files in the current directory whose extension is `.txt`.  Change as needed. Then for each file run `wc -l` and form a data frame from it.

(If you are on Windows then install Rtools and ensure that `\Rtools\bin` is on your PATH.)

```
filenames <- dir(pattern = "[.]txt$")
wc <- function(x) shell(paste("wc -l", x), intern = TRUE)
DF <- read.table(text = sapply(filenames, wc), col.names = c("count", "filename"))
```

**2) count.fields** An alternative approach is to use `count.fields`.  This does not make use of any external commands.  `filenames` is from above.

```
sapply(filenames, function(x) length(count.fields(x, sep = "\1")))
```